# how same key is used across processes to communicate each other using shared memory

Tags: unix, ipc, shared-memory, systems-programming

I learned that it is necessary to use same key in both two processes to communicate using shared memory. In sample code I've seen , the key is hard coded in both programs(sender,receiver). My doubt is in real time how two unexpected processes use the same key. 
I've read about ftok() function, but it asks for file path as argument. But how it is possible in real time as below scenario

suppose  when user give  print to file command from firefox some  other program like ghostscript is going to make a ps/pdf file(assuming it uses shared memory). Here how firefox and ghostscript  will use shared memory

Answer (score 0):

Two processes unknown to each other would need to use a defined (and shared) protocol in order to use shared memory together.  And that protocol would need to include the information about how to get to the shared memory (e.g., an integer value for a shmget call).  Basically, it would need to define a "hard coded" identifier or some method for discovering it.

Without some kind of protocol defining this information (including what is in the memory), it would not be possible for one process to even deduce what was in a memory location that was set up by another process.